# Stacking Listviews in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am writing an app using jQuery mobile, and I am trying to list some items with `listview`. I have two lists I want to display, and I decided to use two separate `listview` for the sake of easy manipulating.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li></li>
       ...
</ul>
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li></li>
       ...
</ul>
```

Everything is going well with this structure, however I noticed that the two lists actually overlapped each other over a small area.

[image]

> The texts "State and Tremont" and "Favorites" are too close to each other.

I tried adding a `<br>` and also `<hr>` but no use.

Any ideas?

Recreating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/2azBP/

Comment: you could use this `.ui-listview {
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list is wrapped in a div with `.ui-content` class which has a -15px margin in the default css of jquery mobile and can be fixed by adding a css rule to overwrite the unneeded rule, for the second listview.

You can also add a 
    `<div style="height: 30px;"></div>`
between the lists,  something like this http://jsfiddle.net/WHZhY/

or styling the first list with a margin bottom.
http://jsfiddle.net/WHZhY/1/

Actually, you should use em or percentages so that it looks ok in all resolutions.

Comment: What's interesting is, in your example fiddle if I remove the `<div>` it looks perfect, but in mine they overlapped. Also I don't want to insert a random `<div>` just for this purpose because it would make the HTML look messy overtime.

Comment: No it doesn't. They become stacked like your picture. You need to click run for the view to update.

Comment: I see. I missed the overlapping part. I guess it must be related to the fact they are different types of listviews, but it's still a css issue that you can solve using only css if you don't want to use a div.

Comment: But by adding height manually doesn't really solve the issue, it's kind of like hiding dust under the sofa. I took a look again and I find that the second listview is actually aligning against the last item's text in the last list and ignoring that there's a block there.

Comment: From the jsfiddle you updated your question with you can clearly see it's a margin: -15px; in the jquery mobile css, which in this case is not needed (.ui-content .ui-listview, .ui-panel-inner>.ui-listview is the offending class). Issue does not reproduce in my fiddles because i had no page (ui-content)

Comment: Yea I figured that it out too and I applied `margin-top: 15px;` to `.ui-content .ui-listview + .ui-listview` to overcome that. It's looking perfect now, thanks.

Comment: I'll update the answer with the full explanation. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `margin-top` on the second ul.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>item1 list1</li>
    <li>item2 list1</li>
</ul>

<ul data-role="listview" style="margin-top:5px;">
    <li>item1 list2</li>
    <li>item2 list2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Listview wrapped in content div has `margin` of `-15px`, this is causing overlapping. You need to override margins of `.ui-listview` at least `margin-bottom: 14px`.

```
.ui-content .ui-listview {
  margin-bottom: 14px !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xgvqA/)**